# An error with my code that I just cant figure out

Tags: python, linux

Code:

```
current = input (" Now subtract it by 1. Uh-Oh, My calculator is broken, please tell me what the difference is.")
current = int(current)

print (" OK, my calulator is up and running. We must multiply the number  with 13. Its alright, I have the answer here.")
print (current*13 + " is the product")
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/birthday trick.py", line 13, in <module>
print (current*13 + " is the product")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Please tell me what I can do to improve my code.

Answer (score 0):

The error `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'` means Python is unable to add a string to an integer. In that case, `current` is an integer and `" is the product"` is the string.

To fix the issue you can do as follows :

```
print("%d is the product"  % current  * 13)
```